# Wicket ComponentNotFoundException: Component has been removed from page

Tags: wicket

I have list with ajax link in each row. this link manage own row removeing process. whole list wrapped with WebMarkupContainer.
By pressing the link, called next logic
1) item removed from DB.
2) updated list model
3) target.add(wmc) - add WebMarkupContainer to ajax for updating

since list has more then one element each remove action crashed on render stage. So after refresh page i see that action was done, but problem happened after that

```
  IKickListener onKickListener = new IKickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onKickListener(ListItem<Consultant> item, AjaxRequestTarget target) {

            Cons modelObject = item.getModelObject();
            mUserDAO.remove(modelObject.accountId, getId());

            updateListModel();
            target.add(mWmc);
            target.appendJavaScript("console.log("kicked")");
        }
    };

        mWmc = new WebMarkupContainer("wmc");
        mWmc.setOutputMarkupId(true);
        add(mWmc);
        ListView listView = new ConsListView("consList", new PropertyModel<List<? extends Cons>>(this, "consultants"), onKickListener);
        mWmc.add(listView);
```

and populate method of my list

```
@Override
protected void populateItem(final ListItem<ConsPanel.Cons> item) {
    item.add(new IndicatingAjaxLink("actionKick") {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
            mKickListener.onKickListener(item, target);
        }
    });
}
```

then i recived next stack trace

```
org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.ComponentNotFoundException: Component 'consPanelPlace:cons:wmc:consList:2:actionKick' has been removed from page.
    at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.respond(ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.java:177)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle$HandlerExecutor.respond(RequestCycle.java:865)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.RequestHandlerStack.execute(RequestHandlerStack.java:64)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.execute(RequestCycle.java:265)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequest(RequestCycle.java:222)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequestAndDetach(RequestCycle.java:293)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequestCycle(WicketFilter.java:261)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequest(WicketFilter.java:203)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doFilter(WicketFilter.java:284)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1081)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1566)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1523)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I use wicket 7.0.0-M5

**UPDATE**
I have found, that when i have more then 1 item in list, ajax callback attached only for first one. But on click action removed all items except one. Also ajax link called items count times.

Comment: How often do you have to click for this error to appear?

Comment: each time when i have more then one item

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I fount the problem. I have had same id not wicket:id, but general id, at each item. so listener had attached to first one, because wicket ajax listen for it. then it had called few times.
Problem was in markup.

```
<span class="btn" wicket:id="actionKick" id="kick">Kick</span>
                                         ^^^^^^^^^---problem was here
```